# Getting Error While Reading Empty cell in CSV file

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-io, read.csv

I am new to .csv file reading in java. I am getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1 when empty cell is encountered while reading.

```
Error:
ZZZ::[ICD10Dx, A0102]
ZZZ::[ICD10Dx, A1884]
ZZZ::[ICD10Dx, A5206]
ZZZ::[ICD10Dx]
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

Java Code:
```

public class CsvDTO implements Serializable {

```
private String codeType;
private String codes;

public CsvDTO() {
}
```

//Getters and Setters

List xmlLines = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream.getInputStream()))
.lines()
.skip(1) //Skips the first n lines, in this case 1
.map(s -> {

```
                    String[] values = s.split(",");
                    System.out.println("ZZZ::"+Arrays.toString(values));
                    CsvDTO dto = new CsvDTO();
                    dto.setCodeType((values[0].length() <=0)?"": values[0]);
                    dto.setCodes((values[1].length() <=0)? "": values[1]);
                return dto;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

CSV File:

[image]

Comment: check the array length. not the length value of the cell content